# What are the limits for uploading videos into G+ Communities?

Tags: google-plus

Looking to find out:

- maximum number of videos that can be uploaded into each community
- maximum length for each video (in minutes)
- maximum file size for each uploaded video

Answer (score 2):

According to Google's [Photo and video upload size options](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/156348?hl=en)

> You can upload an unlimited number of videos that are less than 15
>   minutes long and 1080p or lower resolution. Videos longer than 15
>   minutes long, or taken at a higher resolution than 1080p, will count
>   against your Google Drive storage quota. [Learn more about Google Drive
>   storage.](https://www.google.com/settings/storage/)

Since you can now connect your G+ and YouTube accounts, the YouTube guidelines [Upload videos longer than 15 minutes](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71673) apply:

> By default, you can upload videos that are 15 minutes long. To upload
>   longer videos, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Visit the upload page at www.youtube.com/my_videos_upload
> 2. Click Increase your limit at the bottom of the page, or visit
>      https://www.youtube.com/verify
> 3. Follow the steps to verify your account with a mobile phone. Currently we aren’t able to offer other
>      ways to verify your account.
>
> [image: YouTube Increase Your Limit]
>
> Once you’ve increased your limit, make sure you’re using an up-to-date
>   version of your browser so you can upload files greater than 20GB.

There is no maximum number of videos.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I just want to make sure that those parameters you referred to (which are for personal G+ Profiles as I understand it) are in fact the same parameters that apply to content uploaded to a G+ Community, especially if the user uploading video isn't the owner of said community. There doesn't seem to be any official Community-specific media guidelines posted anywhere.

Comment: @Edwin as far as I have found that's the case

Comment: @Edwin best way to thank someone here is to upvote and/or accept (that way people in the future know what answers others found to be helpful). Good luck!